# Can not connect to mongoDB with MongoClient

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some trouble connecting to a remote mongoDB instance.

```
var http = require('http'),
express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
CollectionDriver = require('./collectionDriver').CollectionDriver,
FileDriver = require('./fileDriver').FileDriver; //<---

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.bodyParser()); // <-- add

var mongoHost = 'mongodb://username:password@ds033170.mongolab.com';
var mongoPort = 33170;
var fileDriver;  //<--
var collectionDriver;

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort));

mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
  if (!mongoClient) {
      console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
      process.exit(1);
  }
  var db = mongoClient.db("myDatabaseName");

  fileDriver = new FileDriver(db); //<--
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db);
});
```

If I start node on my local machine and enter localhost:7777, I always get the following error from above in the console:

**Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first**

What might be the reason for that?

Comment: no, it is running on a mongoLab Server on port 33170; the node app is running on port 7777 on my local machine

Comment: OK, I was confused by what you meant by "enter localhost:7777". What does `err` contain in the `mongoClient.open` callback?

Comment: Error: failed to connect to [mongodb://username:password@ds033170.mongolab.com:33170] ... that makes sense because I can only access: mongodb://username:password@ds033170.mongolab.com:33170/myDatabaseName. But how can I establish that?

Comment: The docs on `MongoClient` are confusing. Use [`MongoClient.connect`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs on `MongoClient` are confusing.  It's typically best to use `MongoClient.connect` instead of creating your own `MongoClient` object and calling `open` on it as you can include the database name into the `connect` call's `url` parameter.

So something like:

```
MongoClient.connect(
    'mongodb://username:password@ds033170.mongolab.com:33170/myDatabaseName',
    function(err, db) { ... });
```